# Clustering adjacent polygons with values over a given threshold with Python

Tags: python, geopandas, clustering, spatial-cluster

I have a GeoPandas dataframe that looks like the following

```
    geometry                                            raster_val
0   POLYGON ((1.85626 49.12003, 1.85626 49.11171, ...   28.530001
1   POLYGON ((1.87290 49.12003, 1.87290 49.11171, ...   28.930000
2   POLYGON ((1.88123 49.12003, 1.88123 49.11171, ...   28.670000
3   POLYGON ((1.89788 49.12003, 1.89788 49.11171, ...   28.510000
4   POLYGON ((1.90620 49.12003, 1.90620 49.11171, ...   29.969999
```

that I can show

```
f,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
gdf.plot(column='raster_val', scheme='quantiles', legend=True, ax=ax)
```

[image]

I would like to cluster all the adjacent polygons with a given values and create `macropolygons` based on such aggregration. Let say I want to create macropolygons that have `raster_val > 33`

Answer (score 1):

You can get macro-polygons by creating bins from the raster value column with [pandas cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) and then dissolve on the new binned column with [geopandas dissolve](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.dissolve.html).

Answer (score 0):

Select polygons where GeoDataFrame's raster values greater than 33

```
macropolygons  = gdf[gdf['raster_val'] > 33]
```